# How to read servlet data from Google map

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps, servlets

I have a google map that is reading data from Json and creating a map with markers.but i need to read the data from a servlet and show that data in those markers.This is my code ..

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!--        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCHxqDYORKL_m7OXWHM1BKqVWxXYmA0y-s&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var json = [
            {
                "title": "Stockholm",
                "lat": 59.3,
                "lng": 18.1,
                "description": "Stockholm is the capital and the largest city of Sweden and constitutes the most populated urban area in Scandinavia with a population of 2.1 million in the metropolitan area (2010)"
            },
            {
                "title": "Oslo",
                "lat": 59.9,
                "lng": 10.8,
                "description": "Oslo is a municipality, and the capital and most populous city of Norway with a metropolitan population of 1,442,318 (as of 2010)."
            },
            {
                "title": "Copenhagen",
                "lat": 55.7,
                "lng": 12.6,
                "description": "Copenhagen is the capital of Denmark and its most populous city, with a metropolitan population of 1,931,467 (as of 1 January 2012)."
            }
        ]



        var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

        function initialize()
        {
            var mapProp = {
                center:myCenter,
                zoom:5,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);



           // marker.setMap(map);

            for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
                var data=json[i];
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); 

                // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.description
                });


            }
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {    
                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
</body>
```

This is my code .someone please help.